# Alternative to output buffering to put eval'd code into a variable

Tags: php

I need to evaluate some php that is in a variable, and put the output into another variable.

I have the following code

```
                ob_start();
                $php = "echo 'cat';";
                eval($php);
                $result = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                echo $result;
```

Is there any way to do it without output buffering? Possibly with create_function?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the obligatory "eval is dangerous" that's mentioned right off the bat in the documentation ([php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)).

---

Second, why don't you put `$result` inside your eval?

```
$php = "$result = 'cat';
```

and then you'll have your result variable all set already.

Comment: I didn't think of assigning the result into a variable inside the eval... Silly me

Comment: Yep, not too tricky. But, I say again with lots of hand-waving and "whoooo" noises, "don't use eval!" pretty much ever.  It's asking for trouble, and there's always a better way to do it - *every* time.

Comment: Yes I know it's evil ;)

Comment: What I need to do is inject php onto a page, and the php is coming from an external source (which I control), and I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Well for that sort of thing you're on your own, I'm afraid.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = '';
eval('$output="cat";');
echo $output;
```